# How do I sort ElasticSearch when it's empty?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

Sometimes, I have nothing in the index, sometimes, I have some documents. That's just the nature of my application.  When the index does contain documents, I sort by "final_score" descending. My query looks like this:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all":{}
    },
    "sort":[
         { "final_score" : "desc" }
    ]
}
```

However, this query breaks when there are 0 documents in the index.  I would have to remove the sort to make the query work.

How can I make this query work with any amount of documents (0, or more?)

Comment: Is this final_score a field ?

Comment: @progrrammer Yes, it's a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have field and ask elasticsearch to sort by that field then there is problem, 
So,Have mapping for `final_score`, so that it will not throw error (if nothing is indexed also).

Example:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/index/type/_mapping
{
   "type": {
      "properties": {
         "final_score": {
            "type": "integer"
         }
      }
   }
}
```